# Emeditor crashing after a certain regex

Tags: emeditor

I have a 10gb file which I am trying to edit.
I've edited a few things in it and it works fine until I need to do find and replace `)` with new line `\n`

When I try to replace it for a few lines it works but when I try to replace the whole file the progress bar fills to 100% but instead of finishing it just stops there and crashes.

I tried splitting the file to 1gb pieces and then edit but same problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

For very large files, you should use **escape sequences** rather than **regular expressions**. Using escape sequences should process replaces much faster than regular expressions.

Comment: I see, sorry for confusion, but isn't this escape sequence only? I did select escape sequence option when using find and replace

Comment: You can replace `)` with `\n` using the Escape Sequence option. If you need a regular expression, what is your regular expression?

Comment: I am sorry I did not understand. I meant if I can use regex instead of the current solution I hope it won't stuck/crash.

Progress shows 100% but it just stuck there for hours, I am having this issue only when I try find and replace, when I try mass removing a string from whole 10gb file it takes a couple of mins and finishes the job without issue.

Comment: Please clarify your question. You will have to write exact search/replace strings, all options (including in the Advanced dialog), and a sample file (preferably small and simple). Please write a step-by-step procedure to explain the issue. You can also post some screenshots to explain the issue.

Comment: I did not go to advanced dialog option, what settings do I need to change there when performing this search and replace command?

I will tell you what is working... when I select around 100-200 lines and then search replace `)` with new line `\n` for that portion it works. But stops working when I do it for the whole file. Whole file has 10k lines.

Comment: Please click **Reset** button in the Advanced dialog to make sure you are using the default settings. Again, please clarify your question to help you.